# NameError: name "plt" is not defined

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: ошибка в названии. не пойму как ее решить]только начинаю осваивать программу

Comment: Просьба указать в чем ошибка и как ее исправить

Comment: Совершенно нечитаемо. Советую посмотреть правила размещения вопросов и разместить соответственно, чтобы вам могли ответить.

Comment: Код нужно прикладывать к вопросу в виде текста. И ошибки тоже по возможности в виде текста.

Answer (score 1):

У вас пропущен видимо один из довольно стандартных импортов:

```py
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
```